# Crate AMI Performance Lower With Flask-RESTful Endpoint on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, flask-restful, crate

Launched a Simple Crate AMI EC2 Instance and opened up the ports for Crate on 4200 and 5000 for Flask.

When I run the EC2 instance with Crate AMI, the speeds are slower but still fast enough (~1-2 Second), but when I call the same with the Flask Endpoint which calls the Crate DB (on the same instance) by passing a query to it, it takes close to 10 seconds.

I tested the endpoint on a localhost and there was no change to the speed execution as such. Hence, I've ruled out the code being the problem.

My questions:

- Why are the queries being run through the Flask-Restful endpoint on EC2 so slow?
- Does it make a difference in speed performance to make an EC2 AMI from scratch and install CrateDB into it, than an out-of-the-box Crate AMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be one of several things, mostly however I suspect a 'hardware' issue:

- Are the hardware specs the same? more cores, more memory, SSD vs spinning disks?
- Is the environment variable `CRATE_HEAP_SIZE` set to half the available RAM? (`/etc/sysconfig/crate`)
- Is the `CREATE TABLE` statement the same? A different number of cores result in a different number of shards if not specified. Oversharding/undersharding will degrade performance noticeably.

I am assuming the table size and queries are the same ;) otherwise seemingly minor changes can make a difference in performance. [Partitioned tables](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/partitioned_tables.html#partitioned-tables) optimize if the partition column is in the `WHERE` clause, as well as queries hitting the primary key(s) directly are way faster. Similarly, aggregations/comparisons on Strings are slower than on numeric types etc.

Cheers, Claus